# Phpbb template edited but not working

Tags: phpbb3

I need little help editing the PHPBB prosilver template to add a link/button. the file name is  "viewtopic_body.html". tried to edit it but it show no changes on the page. Even if i delete all content in the file, even the it show the page.

Comment: Did you clear cach? ACP > Purge the cache

Comment: I solved it dude.Thanks